Elements don't set to active when they are supposed to
The footstep gameobjects are supposed to be set to active when the footsteps() function is called, but it doesnt, i can see in the editor that the "currently" bools for walking and running updates to true upon walking and running which tells me the function should be called. Keep in mind the running() function works fine and it plays as it should.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class walkingSounds : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject footstep;
    public GameObject footstep2;
    public GameObject footstep3;
    public GameObject running1;
    public GameObject running2;
    public GameObject running3;
    public int rndWalkSound;
    public int rndRunSound;

    public bool grounded = false;
    public bool currentlyWalking = false;
    public bool currentlyRunning = false;

    void Start()
    {
        footstep.SetActive(false);
        footstep2.SetActive(false);
        footstep3.SetActive(false);
        running1.SetActive(false);
        running2.SetActive(false);
        running3.SetActive(false);
    }

    void Update()
    {
        void footsteps()
        {
            rndWalkSound = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if (currentlyWalking == false && grounded == true)
            {
                if (rndWalkSound == 1)
                {
                    footstep.SetActive(true);
                }
                else if (rndWalkSound == 2)
                {
                    footstep2.SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    footstep3.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
        }

        void running()
        {
            rndRunSound = Random.Range(1, 4);
            if (currentlyRunning == false && grounded == true)
            {
                if (rndRunSound == 1)
                {
                    running1.SetActive(true);
                }
                else if (rndRunSound == 2)
                {
                    running2.SetActive(true);
                }
                else
                {
                    running3.SetActive(true);
                }
            }
        }

        void StopFootsteps() 
        {
            footstep.SetActive(false);
            footstep2.SetActive(false);
            footstep3.SetActive(false);
        }

        void StopRunningFootsteps()
        {
            running1.SetActive(false);
            running2.SetActive(false);
            running3.SetActive(false);
        }


        if (Input.GetKey("w") && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) 
           || Input.GetKey("a") && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) 
           || Input.GetKey("s") && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) 
           || Input.GetKey("d") && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)) 
        {
            footsteps();
            currentlyWalking = true;
        } 
        else if (Input.GetKey("w") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift)
        || Input.GetKey("a") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) 
        || Input.GetKey("s") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) 
        || Input.GetKey("d") && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            running();
            currentlyRunning = true;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp("w") 
           || Input.GetKeyUp("a") 
           || Input.GetKeyUp("s") 
           || Input.GetKeyUp("d") 
           || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift)) 
        {
            StopFootsteps();
            currentlyWalking = false;

            if (!Input.GetKey("w") 
                && !Input.GetKey("a") 
                && !Input.GetKey("s") 
                && !Input.GetKey("d")) 
            {
                StopFootsteps();
                currentlyWalking = false;
            }
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            StopRunningFootsteps();
            currentlyRunning = false;
        }

        if (grounded == false)
        {
            StopFootsteps();
        }
    }
    private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        grounded = true;
    }

    private void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        grounded = false;
    }
}



I have no idea what is wrong, I don't know if it's in the code or in the editor, but it worked and then suddenly it just stopped working, and now I can't find what is wrong.

Some general notes: I would be against those local functions .. it makes your update quite bloated and hard to read imho. Also have you considered using the Input.GetKey overloads taking KeyCode? It's a bit cleaner and faster than going string based .. the check for (!Input.GetKey("w") && ... is nested and only applied if any key is going up .. is that intended?

why do you have if w,a,s,d or left shift, stop walking and inside, if !wasd stop again?  Id say time for some housework, if things arent reacting as you might thing, through debug statements see whats going on

"I have no idea what is wrong" Then add some logs, so you know which methods are called and which ones are not.

As far as I can see it should work, unless your gameobject collision somehow set grounded to false (by the way it would be good to call boolean as isGrounded). So try to set grounded to true and disable part where you set it to false. Then you will get only cases with pressing wasd and shift. Also try to put debug point or call debug.log() (or whatever command that output text to your consol) and see how it is going.

It might be better to use a state machine  between idle, walking and running. It should clean up your update to make things easier to read and to debug.

Oh, by the way, do you have any other objects with collider box on them. I realized that you does not checking with what object collision has been detected. So colliding with like bullet or tree or whatever you have there will also set grounded to false and deactivate you game object.

you should remove these parts from within your Update() method;
    void StopFootsteps() 
    {
        footstep.SetActive(false);
        footstep2.SetActive(false);
        footstep3.SetActive(false);
    }

As they are turning your GameObjects to false. Instead, you can use them as following (P.S. I changed all your multiple IFs into a Switch);
void footsteps()
    {
        rndWalkSound = Random.Range(1, 4);
        if (currentlyWalking == false && grounded == true)
        {
            switch(rndWalkSound):
               case 1:
                  footstep.SetActive(true);
               break;

               case 2:
                  footstep2.SetActive(true);
               break;

               case 3:
                  footstep3.SetActive(true);
               break;
        }else{
               footstep.SetActive(false);
               footstep2.SetActive(false);
               footstep3.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

Same applies to your running part as well.
If this post helps you please mark it as solved !

StopFootsteps() is a local function that get called on KeyUp or OnCollisionExit, it does not immidiatly disable game objects. You are missing {} from your switch. And, by the way, nesting is bad.
